# Get google analytics active goals data

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I want to get a analytics report for all active goals, for all profiles that belongs to the web properties that have a adwords account linked.

What I did so far is getting the [account summaries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAccountSummariesGuide), loop through each account, loop through each property and and check if it has an adwords link.

Then foreach account that has adwords link loop again to get the profiles and for each profile get the goals. Then foreach active goal get a report.

My question is if is there a simpler way to achieve this task doing less requests.

P.S. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: I think you are doing it correctly.  Yes it is a lot of requests, but there really isn't anyway around that.

Comment: I was thinking to use some filters (I don't know much about filters) to reduce some of the requests.

Comment: filters are only for getting data out of the Reporting API.  this is all the management API.  you used to be able to add a search parameter to some of the management requests.   But that's really not going to help you much its only going to return less data which doesn't really matter it will still be the same number of requests you will be making